# NodeJS and ExpressJS - Javascript files load but CSS files don't

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am building a web app using NodeJS, ExpressJS, AngularJS, Bootstrap, and a Postgres DB using Sequelize. I am having problems with loading all of my "asset" files when I load up my index.html page.

So here is my structure:

- server.js
- app

  - index.html
  - app.js
  - assets

    - css

      - styles.css
    - img
    - js

      - javascript files

Here is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var database = require('./config/database');
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

require('./api/routes.js')(app);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + port);
});
```

Here is my index.html file:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <link src='assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link src='assets/css/styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="controller">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    </nav>
    <script src='assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src='assets/js/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='assets/js/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='assets/js/angular-resource.min.js'></script>
    <script src='assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='assets/js/modernizr.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that, with my current setup, when I start up node and hit my localhost:5000 the index.html file loads along with all of my javascript files inside the assets/js folder. When I open up chrome dev tools I can actually see that folder being loaded in the sources pane. However, NONE of my CSS loads. Why is that? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have basically exhausted all other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first post, so be generous. :)

you should actually use href to reference your css files.

```
<link href='assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='assets/css/styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

See here: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import

Comment: Omg I can't believe I didn't see that. Works now, thanks a bunch man!